# symfony form submit breaks when method DELETE is used

Tags: php, forms, symfony, post, http-method

In symfony 3 this code below worked fine. Upgrading to symfony 5 it doesn't.

Controller:

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, ACRGroup $aCRGroup)
{
    
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($aCRGroup);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    //Check for related entities (if found, prevent deletion)
        $reasons ="";

        //Users
        if (!$aCRGroup->getUsers()->isEmpty()) {
            $reasons .= 'användare ';
        }

        //DebitPeriods
        if (!$aCRGroup->getDebitPeriods()->isEmpty()) {
            $reasons .= 'debiteringsperioder  ';
        }

        //Analysis
        if (!$aCRGroup->getAnalysis()->isEmpty()) {
            $reasons .= 'analyser(flygsäkerhetsbedömningar) ';
        }

        //Positions
        if (!$aCRGroup->getPositions()->isEmpty()) {                
            $reasons .= 'positioner ';
        }

        if (strlen($reasons)>0) {

            $this->helper->flash('fail','Kunde inte radera gruppen '.$aCRGroup->getName().' eftersom det finns '.$reasons.' knutna till den.');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('group_index');               

        } else {
            $groupName = $aCRGroup->getName();

            $em = $this->em;
            $em->remove($aCRGroup);
            $em->flush($aCRGroup);              

            $this->helper->flash('success','Raderade gruppen '.$groupName);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('group_index');
        }
    }
```

Form:

```
 */
private function createDeleteForm(ACRGroup $aCRGroup)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('group_delete', array('id' => $aCRGroup->getId())))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

The form looks like this when rendered

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="/webtools/public/group/20/delete">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input class="btn btn-danger pull-right" type="submit" value="Ta bort Grupp" onclick="return confirm('Är du säker att du vill ta bort denna Grupp?')">
    <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="31b74d.RTs_QX5H9-4T_S5iQXKLD7G4z_3sQI_6TM_Xepg3rYY.NmQNbCdqnatjsxsOcUXgftD_roiZAeW7C_iiIsEFgPYxCXMtJiXClEmnHg">
</form>
```

Routing:

```
group_delete:
    path:     /{id}/delete
    defaults: { _controller: App\Controller\ACRGroupController::deleteAction }
    methods:  DELETE
```

This results in error

> no route found for "POST
> http://localhost:8888/webtools/public/group/20/delete": Method Not
> Allowed (Allow: DELETE)

Changing the routing to methods: POST ...

```
group_delete:
    path:     /{id}/delete
    defaults: { _controller: App\Controller\ACRGroupController::deleteAction }
    methods:  POST
```

... that allows the code to step into the controller, but then the test for

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
```

always returns false. A dd($form) reveals that form isSubmitted indeed equals false.

Apparently that was due to the conflict between the routing expecting POST and the CreateDeleteForm generating a form with method DELETE. So changing the form generating function to match POST...

```
->setMethod('DELETE')
```

... makes it all work again.

But why is DELETE seemingly no longer allowed? Did I miss something here, isn't the DELETE method standard by now?

Comment: HTML forms don't generally support DELETE, if that's what you're getting at.

Comment: As the rendered form shows, the html method is post, but a hidden field tells symfony to look for method delete. But for some reason it works differently now than it used to in the previous symfony versions